# What role does "municipatum" play in this sentence?

Tags: medieval-latin, grammar-identification, agreement

The abbot [Berno of Reichenau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berno_of_Reichenau), in the opening sentence of his *Prologus in Tonarium*, some time between 1021 and 1036, called himself the following:

> licet parvus meritis, **servus** tamen Dei Genitricis Virginis **municipatum** in arce divinae speculationis
>
> though small in merit, still **a servant** of the Virgin Mother of God **citizenship(?)** in the ark of divine speculation

I am puzzled how *municipatum* fits into the rest of the phrase. I figure it is not an adjective here, for it doesn't agree grammatically with *servus*. Could it perhaps be an accusative object to *servus*, as in "the one serving the citizenship of the Virgin Mother of God"? But then why *servus* and not, say, *servans*?

Sources: [Gerbert](https://chmtl.indiana.edu/tml/9th-11th/BERNPRO) [Migne](https://chmtl.indiana.edu/tml/9th-11th/BERNMUS)

Comment: Can you quote around that passage or at least link to a fuller version? It might have to do with surrounding text.

Comment: One thing is certain, ‘arce’ does not mean “ark” (that would be ‘arca’), but is the ablative of ‘arx’, which to me suggest that ‘arce speculationis’ is a watchtower of sorts (‘divinae’). My feeling (sorry) for ‘municipatum’ is it’s a supine-like thing, “for a citizenship,” “to build a dwelling-place,” kinda. But yes, context might help.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It's part of the author's salutation, so there isn't much more context than what I quoted.

Comment: @Batavulus Thanks for clarifying. The work is a treatise on music theory that opens a book of Gregorian chants, and so 'speculatio' here is the 'theoria' or the mind's 'seeing' that comes from a study of the liberal arts such as Musica.

Comment: @Coemgenus Thanks! It seems indeed that there wasn't more context of use, but it's always good to check. Sometimes an unexpected accusative is the object of a verb that comes half a page later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I had been thinking erroneously of the second declension. But, if *municipatus* is a noun here, not an adjective, then naturally it would be declined to the **fourth** declension, whose genitive plural ending *-uum* was oft elided as *-um* in Medieval Latin.

I suppose the sentence might then be translated something like this:

> servus tamen Dei Genitricis Virginis municipatuum in arce divinae speculationis
>
> still a servant to the dwellings of the Virgin Mother of God in the fortress of divine speculation.

By which I suppose he is referring to the monastic communities.

Comment: municipatus in ML can mean "warden" or "castellan", some kind of officer. So perhaps, "servant of the wardens ... in the fortress"